# SharePoint 2010: Custom dictionary weird behavior

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm following [these](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263242.aspx) instructions to create a custom dictionary.

Its content looks like

```
2.0
2.1
```

Issue is, when I search `"2.0"`, it brings documents containing `"2"`, *which I don't want!*

Is this a SharePoint bug, by-design behavior, am I writing the custom dictionary wrongly, or am I mistaken about what custom dictionaries are for? Looks like SharePoint is converting 2.0 to 2 before looking it up in the custom dictionary, isn't it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation, it seems to be an issue caused by search not honoring custom dictionary but, before considering it, reducing "2.0" to "2".

Answer (score 0):

probably it looks like their is a problem with your steps you have followed

see the blog link provided above and verify that you have a followed all steps i would suggest 
to repeat all steps again

2 steps are most important re starting the search service on all application servers and full crawl

Comment: Thanks, but I double checked them.

Comment: I confirmed this is an issue that will be fixed in future versions.